# Handle range operator with positive and negative range?

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to store the second index to fifth element from last index from splitting using range operator.

```
my $s = "a-b-c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v-a-t-a-v"; 
my @ar = (split "-",$s)[2..-5]; 
print @ar;
```

Expected output is `c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v`

As like below I want to store

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v-a-t-a-v
    |                 |          
    2                 |
                      -5
     __________________
  How to store these element
```

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear at all. Please explain in more detail, showing the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @JimGarrison Post edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to put it in an array and then slice it:

```
my $s = 'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v-a-t-a-v'; 
my @arr1 = split /-/, $s;
my @arr2 = @arr1[2..@arr1-5];
```

or

```
my @arr = do { my @arr = split /-/, $s; @arr[2..@arr-5] };
```

or

```
my @arr = map @$_[2..$#$_-5], [ split /-/, $s ];
```

To do it all at once without an extra variable, you would need to pick an arbitrary size bigger than the array would be and do two slices:

```
my @arr = grep defined, (grep defined, (split /-/, $s)[2..999])[-999..-5];
```

(which is much less efficient than just using a separate array).

Explanation: assuming $s is `'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v-a-t-a-v'`:

The first slice (2..999) will produce a list of `'c', 'd', 'e', ..., 't', 'a', 'v'` followed by 984 `undef` values, since the slice asks for that many elements that don't exist.  The inner `grep defined` removes those `undef` values, leaving the 14 element `c` through `v` list.

The second slice (-999..-5) produces a list beginning with 985 `undef` elements (since indexes -999 through -15 don't exist) followed by `'c', 'd', 'e', ..., 'c', 'a', 'v'`.  The outer `grep defined` removes those `undef` values, leaving the desired 10 element list.

Comment: I like your last method but I don't know the last index.

Comment: @mkHun: you don't have to know the last index, you just have to know how big it might ever be.

Comment: why did you use `defined` in two times.? Shall you explain it.

Comment: @mkHun added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. `2..-5` is an empty list because `2` is greater than `-5`.

You'd have to use an array:

```
my $s = "a-b-c-d-e-f-g-f-e-c-a-v-a-t-a-v"; 
my @ar = split /-/, $s;
print join("-", @ar[2 .. $#ar-4]), "\n";
```

`$#ar` is the last index in `@ar`, which makes the range computation work.